# C# How to get files from an xbox directory

Tags: c#, xna, xbox360

I am trying to get a list of all files in a specific xbox directory as shown below, however I get a 'System.NotSupportedException' - Additional information: The given path's format is not supported.

```
var path = @"XE:\MyDirectory";
var files = Directory.GetFiles(path);
```

Does anyone know a way around it?
Thanks

Comment: Is your MyDirectory something that you have created?

Comment: Yes. Really I just need to get the files such as the .pdb and .dump files.

Comment: Have you tried using Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() to see if that works?

Comment: That will return the directory of the C# tool I am using. (e.g. C:\MyTool\bin).

Comment: I need to get a list of files stored on a directory created on the xbox dev kit folder and copy them to a specific location on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing built into the XNA Framework to allow you to do this. For getting the file names you can't use the [GetFileNames method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.storage.storagecontainer.getfilenames.aspx) of the StorageContainer class?